# Why is there an inductor sort of a thing inside this antenna?

Tags: antenna, frequency, gsm

I have a 20cm antenna exactly of the same shape as shown in figure. I want to know why is there a inductor sort of a shape in its monopole? What is its purpose? Does it affects its designed frequency? Or it has to do something with its gain or impedance matching....? 
[image: External GSM Antenna or Whip Mount Antenna]

Comment: compare the physical and the approximate required electrical length for the desired frequency

Comment: It has **two** inductors.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The length of antenna as described above is 20cm... If it is a quater wave antenna (lambda/4) the wavelength comes out to be 80cm (but I dont know if it really is quater wave). And by using the speedOfLight=frequency*wavelength the frequency turns out to be 374.74 MHz which is certainly not the frequency of GSM...

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes yes thanks for specifying .... But do you know the purpose of any of it?

Comment: It looks like a [Loading coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loading_coil) to me.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks a lot! Its is really called a Loading coil.

Comment: This looks like a vertical phased array (having gain). Omnidirectional in the horizontal plane. What *looks like* a coil is a transmission-line-like matching/phasing section between vertical radiating elements.

Comment: It's likely a dual band antenna intended for both 800 MHz and 1700 MHz GSM bands. It uses the "inductors" to optimize it to receive well on both bands.

Comment: @Andyaka maybe that is the case but if it is there might be some calculations refering to the position and curls of the inductor.. yes this is a dual band antenna as far as i know. But i have also seen antennas without this loading coil serving as dual band.....

Comment: @glen_geek can you give me the referance from where you read this?

Comment: @user73006 An analysis done by L.B.Cebik, W4RNL. An archive search for it was unsuccessful (he was a prolific writer) - I recall his web page was a retro-engineering analysis of the early 900 MHz cell phone antennas that sprouted from many cars.

Comment: @user73006 Some effort has been made to archive L.B.Cebik web pages (thanks to those who've tried). My best guess is his article entitled "Is COCO your cup of tea?" or better yet, "The case of the curly collinear". Best of luck in your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew Morton has mentioned it is a loading coil. Mainly used for impedance matching. I found some calculations in the following article.
[Loaded Quarter Wave Antenna Inductance Calculator](https://m0ukd.com/calculators/loaded-quarter-wave-antenna-inductance-calculator/)